# After the ethereum merge, how can I know the reward address..?

Tags: merge, ethereum, fee, reward

Before the Ethereum merge. The miner received the fee or reward, and the miner was known by looking at the json rpc function "eth_getBlockByNumber".

Now, I know that people who participated in staking get a reward. Has the json-rpc api been added to know how much reward each participant received?? Is there any way to find out?

Answer (score 1):

The RPC API is expected to reflect on the network changes, but currently (September 16, 2022, one day after the merge) it only contains the block producer in the `miner` property (same naming as with PoW for backwards compatibility). It currently does not return the voters list, or staking participants in general.

Comment: Thank you!


Then, at present, which staker has received the fee or reward, can't it be known from the node data??

Is there any way to know other than Json-RPC?

Comment: @Jmob: I'm not aware of any way how to get the list of the voters or reward receivers. However I still need to do a bit more of studying on this... So if anyone is more experienced in this topic, please do share your answers.... There might be some more information in the [docs page](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/rewards-and-penalties/#rewards) or the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) that covers Ethereum in general (while StackOverflow is more focused on the development part).